# Create multiple instance to the same Titan Graph

Tags: java, titan

I am connecting to Titan using,

`TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open("/titan-0.5.2-hadoop2/conf/titan-cassandra.properties");`

According to the documentation, the above statement opens a new connection to Titan graph g.

Is it possible to create multiple instance to the same Titan graph?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried making multiple instances of a graph from a single config file.

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open("conf/gremlin-server/titan-cassandra-solr.properties")
==>standardtitangraph[cassandra:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> graph2 = TitanFactory.open("conf/gremlin-server/titan-cassandra-solr.properties")
==>standardtitangraph[cassandra:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> graph.traversal().V()
16:50:19 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
gremlin> graph2.traversal().V()
16:50:29 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
```

Seems like there are no issues with using two instances of graph simultaneously, although I'm not to sure why you would want this. If you elaborate on your use case hopefully I can help you further.

Comment: my application wants to create multiple transactions with same graph connection. How to do it without facing concurrency issue in cassandra Titan?

Comment: Graph threaded = graph.tx().createThreadedTx(); available in titan 1.0.0 and above. It works, but as  you point out your going to have an independant cache for each thread. So it will work concurrently but not with consistancy until you commit (it has eventual consistancy).